# Why does Sliver App Bar's flexibleSpace parameter have to take a Widget with a const constructor?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I am trying to build a custom scroll view which contains a sliver app bar to achieve something similar to what's shown here:

https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe

However I want to have the word Search and below it I want 3 IconButtons Evenly spaced, when the page (CustomScrollView) is scrolled, I want the 3 IconButtons to be pinned to the top of the SliverAppBar and the Search Text to disappear...

I Tried to achieve the above via the following code:

```
 class SearchPage extends StatelessWidget {

      const SearchPage();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
        const SliverAppBar(
        pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 250.0,
            flexibleSpace: _buildSliverAppBarFlex(),
            );
      }


       Widget _buildSliverAppBarFlex() {
        return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Search", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Row(children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.flight)),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.hotel)),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.drive_eta))
                ])
              ],
            )
        );
      }
    }
```

However I get a warning that flexibleSpace must take a const constructor widget and that the _buildSilverAppBarFlex Widget I've made is not - I cannot add const or final to it either... Any ideas how I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning comes because you are using `const` ahead of your `SliverAppBar`, remove this, and warning will be gone.

So, instead of this

```
const SliverAppBar(...)
```

Use this.

```
SliverAppBar(...)
```

If you want to use `const` there, make sure your `FlexibleSpaceBar` is also a `const` then.

Comment: I don't know if it worked, because I used a completely different approach - but I'll approve - I also have another question:

Suppose I have a SliverAppBar and a SliverList which has a SliverChildListDelegate, how would I go about sticking/pinning the first child in the SliverList to the top of the screen as the SliverAppBar scrolls out/collapses (off the screen)?